# ¿Cómo optimizar o mejorar una consulta en laravel para mostrar los datos en un datatables?

Tags: laravel, oracle, datatables, optimización

Estoy tratando de mostrar varios datos, cerca de 50,000, el detalle que tarda mucho en cargar en el 'datatables' y quisiera poder reducir el tiempo de carga ya que al no cargar rápido la página web me bota ya que tarda mucho.

Este es mi controlador dónde traigo todos los datos de mi consulta y quisiera ver cómo solo traer los campos que necesito para intentar reducir un poco el tiempo:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\importar;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class vista extends Controller
{
    public function vista_inicio()
    {
        $datos = importar::all();


        return \View::make('formulario')->with(
            [
            'datos' => $datos
        ]
        );
    }
}
```

Esta es la vista dónde tengo mi 'datatables':

```
 <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>PROVEEDOR</th>
                <th>ID_ENLACE</th>
                <th>FECHA_FACTURA</th>
                <th>FECHA_INGRESO</th>
                <th>OPCIONES</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @foreach($datos as $datos)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$datos->proveedor}}</td>
                    <td>{{$datos->id_enlace}}</td>
                    <td>{{$datos->fecha_factura}}</td>
                    <td>{{$datos->fecha_ingreso}}</td>

                </tr>
            @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: A que te refieres con datatable? A la librería js https://datatables.net? Pregunto porque no se vé cómo la implementas en tu código

Answer (score 1):

Tu mejor solución es muy probablemente utilizar paginación, y configurar datatables para que trabaje con ajax, en caso que desees ordenar los campos, hacer búsquedas, etc.

En cuanto a reducir la cantidad de campos que deseas seleccionar, utiliza el método select() y le pasas como parámetros los campos, separados por coma:

```
importar::select('campo1', 'campo2', 'campo3')
```

Su documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries#selects

---

En cuanto a la paginación, tienes varias opciones en Laravel, pero supongamos que tomas la opción más común, el método paginate(), al cual le pasas como parámetro la cantidad de elementos que mostrarás por página:

```
importar::select('campo1', 'campo2', 'campo3')->paginate(10);
```

Su documentación: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/pagination#paginating-query-builder-results

---

Por último, es posible incluso que te sirva la funcionalidad de *Lazy collections* de Laravel 6.x, para no cargar todos los registros en memoria, pero puede ser un tema un poco avanzado, o tal vez innecesario según lo que quieras/pretendas hacer:

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#lazy-collections

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de cualquiera de estas dos formas.

```
$datos = importar::select('proveedor','id_enlace','fecha_factura','fecha_ingreso')->get();
```

o

```
$datos = importar::get(['proveedor','id_enlace','fecha_factura','fecha_ingreso']);
```

Comment: Ya que tu respuesta es muy similar a la de Shaz recomiendo editar y ampliar explicando

Answer (score 0):

> `DataTables` tiene otras alternativas para recuperar los elementos que se van a renderizar. La forma de la que estas trabajando va a recuperar los 50.000 elementos, y por mas que te muestre 10 en pantalla, podes apretar `f12` y ver que los 50.000 están impresos en el código `html`, lo que te va a generar serios problemas de performance.

Para esto existe una forma de pasarle datos, por medio de `Ajax`. De esta manera se van a ir cargando únicamente los que necesiten mostrarse en la pagina en la que estés, al pasar de pagina recuperará los que corresponden (si pones mostrar 10 elementos por pagina, podes probar apretar `f12` y ver que solo trae 10 elementos en el `html`, y que estos cambian dinámicamente a medida que cambias de pagina).

El ejemplo que ofrece DataTable es el siguiente

**html**

> Fijate que pone solo `header` y `footer`, omite el `body` (podes omitir el `footer` si no lo necesitas)

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Extn.</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
```

**JavaScript**

> Acá solamente llamas por medio de `ajax`, un archivo desde donde vas a traer los datos en formato JSON

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "data/arrays.php"
    } );
} );
```

**Arrays.txt**

> La idea es que te fijes lo que tiene este documento. Tiene objetos `JSON`, la idea es crear un archivo `php` en lugar de un `txt` como muestra el ejemplo, y en él, un método que devuelva los items de la base de datos en este formato. DataTable se encargará de pasarlos dinámicamente para que tu página cargue sin problemas de performance.

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "Tiger Nixon",
      "System Architect",
      "Edinburgh",
      "5421",
      "2011/04/25",
      "$320,800"
    ],
    [
      "Garrett Winters",
      "Accountant",
      "Tokyo",
      "8422",
      "2011/07/25",
      "$170,750"
    ],
    [
      "Ashton Cox",
      "Junior Technical Author",
      "San Francisco",
      "1562",
      "2009/01/12",
      "$86,000"
    ]
}
```

> Podes ver el ejemplo completo en esta url https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html

Comment: Cabe aclarar que mi respuesta no aplica a solucionar tu problema, sino a mostrarte una alternativa para darle un uso mas dinamico al datatables. Que vengan esos negativos que los paro de pecho.